# No share screen option in Skype

Tags: skype

I have recently downloaded Skype from https://go.skype.com/skype.download. But there's no share screen option after I install it. Have I installed any other version? Or it is something else?

**OS:** Windows 7
**Skype Version:** ...
**Computer:** Desktop PC

Comment: What type of device? Which OS? Were you able to do so before (are you confident with use of Skype, or looking for a manual)?

Comment: Desktop PC Windows 7

Comment: [How do I share my screen in Skype? | Skype Support](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10022/how-do-i-share-my-screen-in-skype)?

Comment: Hi Dhruv welcome on SuperUser. Please [edit] you question to add relevant information as the OS and the version of skype. 
If the link posted by David is useful you can answer to your question too...
Eventually read [ask] page, you may find useful.