# can't see screen share option in skype

Tags: skype

I checked [No share screen option in Skype](https://superuser.com/questions/1291886/no-share-screen-option-in-skype) 
 it mentions https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10022/how-do-i-share-my-screen-in-skype  but I still see no option

I see a plus icon

[image]

But when I click it I get this

[image]

no option to share screen.

Comment: Are you on a call? From the link you posted "**During the call**, tap or click the plus icon in the **call bar**, then choose Share screen. "

Comment: @DavidPostill yes I was on a call at the time I wrote that question. I clicked the plus icon then all those icons popped up and none of them that I can see say "share screen" as the screenshots show

Comment: @DavidPostill next time I am on a call I will look for a plus in the "call bar"